# python debugger executes while command line fails the exact same code snippet

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging, themoviedb-api

I have an odd case where a jason file is loaded and then some data is extracted.
Somehow, this snippet works when I use the VS Code debugger (i.e. Start Debugging OR Start without Debugging).

```
conn.request("GET", reqString, payload)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
#print(data.decode("utf-8"))
data_json = json.loads(data)
print(type(data_json))
ThePages = data_json.get('total_pages')
for j in range(1,ThePages):
        #print('Processing page #', j)
```

Weirdly, I get the TypeError that data_json is NoneType when I run it from the command line, in lieu of (error-free) dictionary type when I run this with the debugger.

```
File "script.py", line 60, in main
    for j in range(1,ThePages):
```

TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Any idea how (all inside VS code) the same code snippet  runs error-free in debugger, yet loads nothing from the terminal or Anaconda Prompt?

Comment: Is VS Code using a different python environment?  Are virtualenvs in play?  Is VS Code accessing the web through a proxy? There could be a lot of factors affecting this.

Comment: No virtual envs. I just open VS Code and start coding. I am not aware of any special proxy or any special settings that would explain the difference between VS Code Debugger (works), VS Code terminal (does NOT work) and Anaconda Prompt (does NOT work).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The command line loaded a list. Programmer error.